# Fazer aparecer/desaparecer imagem ao clicar

Tags: javascript, html, css

Gostaria de que ao usuario clicar no botao do "Tamanho" aparecesse uma imagem de um bolo qualquer junto com o preco que ja consegui.

Meu codigo está assim:

```js
$("#service").change(function() {
  var value = $(this).children("option:selected").val();
  if (value == 1) {
    $("#valor").text("Preço: R$ 70,00");
    //queria add  aqui uma imagem caso ele clicasse aqui
  } else if (value == 2) {
    $("#valor").text("Preço: R$ 100,00");
    //queria add aqui uma imagem caso ele clicasse aqui
  } else if (value == 3) {
    $("#valor").text("Preço: R$ 120,00");
    //queria add aqui uma imagem caso ele clicasse aqui
  } else if (value == 4) {
    $("#valor").text("Preço: R$ 160,00");
    //queria add aqui uma imagem caso ele clicasse aqui
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="service" style="margin: 0 5% 0 13%;" name="service" required class="border-box-contact">
  <option value="" disabled selected>Tamanho</option>
  <option value=1>PP (~1,2kg)</option>
  <option value=2>P (~1,8kg)</option>
  <option value=3>M (~2,5kg)</option>
  <option value=4>G (~3,5kg)</option>
</select>
<br>
<p><span style="display:flex; position:relative; justify-content:center; margin-top: 5%; margin-bottom:0%; font-weight: bolder; font-size: 15px;" id="valor" class="valor"></span></p>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode usar o método [`html`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) para adicionar a imagem e o texto em formato HTML.

Algo assim:

```js
$('#service').on('change', function() {
  var value = $(this)
    .children('option:selected')
    .val()

  if (value == 1) {
    $('#valor').html('<img src="https://picsum.photos/50/50/?image=10" /> Preço: R$ 70,00')
  } else if (value == 2) {
    $('#valor').html('<img src="https://picsum.photos/50/50/?image=20" /> Preço: R$ 100,00')
  } else if (value == 3) {
    $('#valor').html('<img src="https://picsum.photos/50/50/?image=30" /> Preço: R$ 120,00')
  } else if (value == 4) {
    $('#valor').html('<img src="https://picsum.photos/50/50/?image=40" /> Preço: R$ 160,00')
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select style="margin: 0 5% 0 13%;" class="border-box-contact" name="service" id="service" required>
  <option value="" disabled selected>Tamanho</option>
  <option value="1">PP (~1,2kg)</option>
  <option value="2">P (~1,8kg)</option>
  <option value="3">M (~2,5kg)</option>
  <option value="4">G (~3,5kg)</option>
</select>
<br />
<p>
  <span class="valor" id="valor" style="display:flex; position:relative; justify-content:center; margin-top: 5%; margin-bottom:0%; font-weight: bolder; font-size: 15px;"></span>
</p>
```

---

Você pode inclusive reduzir a quantidade de `if`s, se quiser:

```js
$('#service').on('change', function() {
  // Note que as chaves do objeto a seguir combinam com os valores dos elementos
  // <option> que você criou. Por isso, podemos usar o valor do <select> para
  // acessar a imagem e o preço desejados.
  var options = {
    1: '<img src="https://picsum.photos/50/50/?image=10" /> Preço: R$ 70,00',
    2: '<img src="https://picsum.photos/50/50/?image=20" /> Preço: R$ 100,00',
    3: '<img src="https://picsum.photos/50/50/?image=30" /> Preço: R$ 120,00',
    4: '<img src="https://picsum.photos/50/50/?image=40" /> Preço: R$ 160,00'
  }

  $('#valor').html(options[$(this).val()])
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select style="margin: 0 5% 0 13%;" class="border-box-contact" name="service" id="service" required>
  <option value="" disabled selected>Tamanho</option>
  <option value="1">PP (~1,2kg)</option>
  <option value="2">P (~1,8kg)</option>
  <option value="3">M (~2,5kg)</option>
  <option value="4">G (~3,5kg)</option>
</select>
<br />
<p>
  <span class="valor" id="valor" style="display:flex; position:relative; justify-content:center; margin-top: 5%; margin-bottom:0%; font-weight: bolder; font-size: 15px;"></span>
</p>
```

---

**Edit 01:**

Para fazer com que o texto fique **abaixo** da imagem, basta utilizar o seguinte CSS:

```
.valor img {
  display: block;
}
```

Isso fará com que a imagem e o texto fiquem em *linhas* diferentes. :)

Comment: Pode mudar o "style" dentro desse metodo?

Comment: E como eu faço para colocar o preco embaixo da imagem? uso "/n"?

Comment: Editei a resposta. :)

Answer (score 2):

Você pode adicionar uma tag `img` no html com um determinado `id`:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="service" style="margin: 0 5% 0 13%;" name="service" required class="border-box-contact">
  <option value="" disabled selected>Tamanho</option>
  <option value=1>PP (~1,2kg)</option>
  <option value=2>P (~1,8kg)</option>
  <option value=3>M (~2,5kg)</option>
  <option value=4>G (~3,5kg)</option>
</select>
<br>
<img src="" id="imagem" /><br>
<p><span style="display:flex; position:relative; justify-content:center; margin-top: 5%; margin-bottom:0%; font-weight: bolder; font-size: 15px;" id="valor" class="valor"></span></p>
```

e alterar o conteúdo dela dinamicamente com jQuery usando `$(...).attr("src", "caminho/para/imagem")`:

```js
$("#service").change(function() {
  var value = $(this).children("option:selected").val();
  if (value == 1) {
    $("#valor").text("Preço: R$ 70,00");
    $("#image").attr("src", "http://placehold.it/100x100");
  } else if (value == 2) {
    $("#valor").text("Preço: R$ 100,00");
    $("#image").attr("src", "http://placehold.it/100x100");
  } else if (value == 3) {
    $("#valor").text("Preço: R$ 120,00");
    $("#image").attr("src", "http://placehold.it/100x100");
  } else if (value == 4) {
    $("#valor").text("Preço: R$ 160,00");
    $("#image").attr("src", "http://placehold.it/100x100");
  }
});
```

Comment: E como eu faço para colocar o preco embaixo da imagem? uso "/n"?

Comment: Eu alterei o HTML pra deixar a imagem acima do preço. Pra deixar o preço em baixo precisa fazer uma quebra de linha com a tag `<br>` depois da imagem.

Answer (score 2):

Você pode fazer como o **Luiz Felipe** colocou, esta perfeito. Eu só passaria os valores via atributo. Assim caso queira adicionar novos elementos ao **select**, não precisa alterar nada no javascript, ele já fica pronto para receber qualquer quantidade existente no **select**.

Ou seja, basta adicionar ou remover um **option** do select e o resultado final será o mesmo.

```js
$('#service').on('change', function() {
  var value = $(this).children('option:selected')
  $('#valor').html('<img src="'+value.data('imagem')+'" /> Preço: R$ '+value.data('valor')+'')
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select style="margin: 0 5% 0 13%;" class="border-box-contact" name="service" id="service" required>
  <option value="" disabled selected>Tamanho</option>
  <option value="1" data-imagem="https://picsum.photos/50/50/?image=10" data-valor="70,00">PP (~1,2kg)</option>
  <option value="2" data-imagem="https://picsum.photos/50/50/?image=20" data-valor="100,00">P (~1,8kg)</option>
  <option value="3" data-imagem="https://picsum.photos/50/50/?image=30" data-valor="120,00">M (~2,5kg)</option>
  <option value="4" data-imagem="https://picsum.photos/50/50/?image=40" data-valor="160,00">G (~3,5kg)</option>
</select>
<br />
<p>
  <span class="valor" id="valor" style="display:flex; position:relative; justify-content:center; margin-top: 5%; margin-bottom:0%; font-weight: bolder; font-size: 15px;"></span>
</p>
```

Comment: Mano, ótimo! E como eu faço para colocar o preco embaixo da imagem? uso "/n"?

Comment: Cara você pode colocar um <br/> depois da tag da imagem. Mas acho que esse exemplo é mais uma marcação, vale a pena dar uma trabalhada nessa parte para fazer algo elaborado, com css.